# Last-Modified vs ETag http

Tags: java, http

What is the difference between Etag and Last-Modified? As far as my understanding goes:

1. A user wants to retrieve an item from Server for the first time.
2. The server responds with the item and sets "Last-Modified" header.
3. When the user wants to retrieve the item from Server for second, third ... time, the server compares "Last-Modified" header that client sent with item's time of last modification, if those values differ item is returned and new "Last-Modified" value is sent if they are the same, server returns 305 -> indicating that client should retrieve an item from client's cache.

Something like ( in very, very primitive case ):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Integer lastModified = Integer.parseInt(request.getHeader("Last-Modified"));

    String path = request.getPathInfo();
    Long id = Long.valueOf(path.substring(1));

    if( lastModified == null || ! DB.isRelevant(id,lastModified)){
        Data data = DB.getData(id);
        response.setHeader("Last-Modified", String.valueOf(data.getModified()));
        response.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(data));
        response.setStatus(200);
    }else{
        response.setStatus(305);
    }
}
```

Now how comes Etag - weak or strong - in this? As far as I understood, its same thing but instead of "Last-Modified" value, Etag header is sent and its value is some calculated hash.

What is the reason for Etag then or what is the difference?

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

Both the Etag and the Last-Modified date can be used to avoid downloading the entity body when the version in your cache is already up-to-date, but the Etag is designed specifically for this purpose and has a couple advantages:

- How to properly use the LastModified date can be a little confusing.  If an entity is *moved* from one resource to another, for example, does it get a new date or does it keep the original one?  File systems usually keep the date, but HTTP servers should not, because it breaks this use case.  There are a lot of servers out there that are broken in this way.
- If-modified-since breaks if the resource is updated twice in the same second
- If a resource is updated, and then reverted to the previous version, it can get the old Etag and clients that still have to old version of the resource will recognize that they don't have to download it.  It needs to get a later Last-Modified date, though, so all clients that use If-Modified-Since will have to download the new version.